# Finding three functions that interpolates between equitation

Tags: function, math, blending

For a past week I been trying to construct specific functions that would satisfy some the requirements, sadly it was not successful. I decided to give a shot in stack overflow.

I have three shapes in 2D world as shown in the image. Shape A with center `a`, Shape B with center `b` and shape C with center `c`. For this problem shape form does not matter so I will not expand on that. Other important variables are `d_ab` with represents minimum distance between shape A and B, `d_bc` - distance between B and C, `d_ac` - distance between A and C. Also `d_ab`, `d_bc`, `d_ac` ranges from 0 to 1, where 1 represents shapes are touching and 0 their too far from specific threshold.

[Here is the image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYHEY.png)

I am trying to find three new functions:

`f_a(d_ab, d_bc, d_ac) = x`

`f_b(d_ab, d_bc, d_ac) = y`

`f_c(d_ab, d_bc, d_ac) = z`

Firstly, these functions with inputs `d_ab`, `d_bc`, `d_ac` in the left side table should result to values `x`, `y`, `z` right side table:

| d_ab | d_bc | d_ac | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `0` | `0` | `(a+b)/2` | `(a+b)/2` | `c` |
| `0` | `1` | `0` | `a` | `(b+c)/2` | `(b+c)/2` |
| `0` | `0` | `1` | `(a+c)/2` | `b` | `(a+c)/2` |
| `1` | `1` | `1` | `(a+b+c)/3` | `(a+b+c)/3` | `(a+b+c)/3` |
| `0` | `0` | `0` | `a` | `b` | `c` |

Secondly, all other inputs `d_ab`, `d_bc`, `d_ac` that are not described in table (From 0 to 1) should result in interpolated values between closest ensuring continuity (Continuity I am referring there is that small change in input should not produce big difference in output, there is probably better way to describe this mathematically).

For example:

`f_a(0.3, 0, 0) = x`

Most likely will combine equitation's from table:

`f_a(0, 0, 0) = a`
`f_a(1, 0, 0) = (a+b)/2`

Resulting into:

`f_a(0.3, 0, 0) = 0.7 * a + 0.3 * (a+b)/2`

I am curious is there a method to find these kind of functions, I assume there could be more than one that satisfies this requirement. But I am fine with any of it as long it has that continuity that I referred above.

I almost sure there is better way to represent this problem mathematically, but I am not that great with it.